# nginx link nodejs app to subdomain

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, subdomain

I have a dropplet on digital-ocean where I have a `node.js` app and `nginx`.

So, I installed nginx and then in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` I created a new file called `api` where I have the following content:

```
server {
        server_name api.my-website.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000; // this is where the node app lives
        }
}
```

After I create that I restared nginx but if I go to api.my-website.com I dont see anything (my api has a landing page on /), but if I go to my-website.com:9000 I see the landing that should be on api.my-website.com.

Can someone explain me please what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed a symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`?

Comment: I dont think so, I followed a tutorial, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You did not included your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api` file into  `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. You need to include `/etc/nginx/sites-available/api` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` inside `http` module and then restart or reload nginx. Your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` may looks like

```
http {
        # other lines for logging, gzip, etc. 
        # other include may here
        # Your include as following
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/api;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer arif but I already have include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; in nginx.conf